# Making output match whats needed

Tags: java

I have a practice problem that I need to complete and have done everything however I cannot get the output to match whats needed. I have tried some of the google answers but nothing seems to be working. Below is the code and the output I get vs what I want. We are not allowed to modify the main method but only the classes.

I am just confused on how to make the output from each class start on a new line.

There is this statement in the instructions but I don't understand how to go about it:

> the Student class should have a public display function that calls the parent class’ display
>   function,

Code:

```
public class H255{public static void main (String[] args){while (JPL.test()){
  Person pObj = new Person("Albert","Einstein");
  Student sObj = new Student("John","Smith",123456,"First Year","Pullan");
  Teacher tObj = new Teacher("Wayne","Pullan","Computer Science",100000,"Lecturer");
  System.out.println("Person :");
  pObj.Display();
  System.out.println("");
  System.out.println("Student :");
  sObj.Display();
  System.out.println("");
  System.out.println("Teacher :");
  tObj.Display();
}}}

class Person{
  private String FirstName;
  private String LastName;

  public Person(String fName,  String lName){
    this.FirstName = fName;
    this.LastName = lName;
  }

  public void Display(){
    System.out.println("First Name: " + FirstName + " Last Name: " + LastName);
  }
}

class Student extends Person{
  private int id;
  private String standard;
  private String instructor;

  public Student(String fName,  String lName, int  nId, String stnd, String instr){
    super(fName, lName);
    this.id = nId;
    this.standard = stnd;
    this.instructor = instr;
  }

  public void Display(){
    System.out.println("ID: " + id + "Standard: " + standard + "Instructor: " + instructor);
  }
}

class Teacher extends Person{
  private String mainSubject;
  private int salary;
  private String type;

  public Teacher(String fName,  String lName, String sub, int slry, String sType){
    super(fName, lName);  
    this.mainSubject = sub;
    this.salary = slry;
    this.type = sType;
  }

  public void Display(){
    System.out.println("Main Subject: " + mainSubject + "Salary: " 
                         + salary + "Type: " + type );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the writing of main method like these code:

```
System.out.print("Person :");
pObj.Display();
System.out.print("Student :");
sObj.Display();
System.out.print("Teacher :");
tObj.Display();
```

because:the println method has a build in wrap feature, so just replace println with print.

Comment: The purpose of this task was to do this without changing the main method at all.

Comment: it's impossible only if you change the grammar of java.